# How to access variables in a runnable object in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, runnable

I am going to simulate a traffic light system.
I created the Road Class which extends JFrame and implements Runnable.

Inside the run() method I added the logic to increase the Y Position of each car and It is now simulating the movements of cars.
But now I need to check the status of the Traffic Light, before move a car.

This is my TrafficLight class,

```
import java.util.Random;

public class TrafficLight implements Runnable {

volatile boolean stop;

public TrafficLight(boolean stop) {
    this.stop = stop;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    while (true) {
        if (stop) {
            stop = false; //change current status
        } else {
            stop = true;  //change current status
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000 + randomGenerator.nextInt(2000));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
       }
   }
}
```

Is there any way to check this volatile variable **stop**, from my Road Class.

If not please suggest me another solution to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, you should add the `homework` tag?

Comment: It's a bad idea to swallow an `InterruptedException` (which is what you do with your catch block) in a `while (true) ...` block: your application will difficult to shut down gracefully, because the loop won't terminate. Better to rethrow it as a `RuntimeException` if you don't want to handle it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implement an accessor for stop.

```
public class TrafficLight implements Runnable {

   volatile boolean stop;

   // Irrelevant code

   public boolean isStop() {
     return stop;
   }
}
```

Receive the `TrafficLight` on the `Road` class constructor and use it to get access to the stop variable

```
public class Road implements Runnable {

   private TrafficLight trafficLight;

   public Road (TrafficLight trafficLight) {
     this.trafficLight = trafficLight;     
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
     // Irrelevant code
     if(trafficLight.isStop()) {
       // do something
     } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Road (or whoever needs the value) should have access to an instance of TrafficLight and ask it if its green. You can provide a boolean method.

BUT access to this property (stop) should be guarded. volatile keyword doesn't help very much (see below).

I should do something like:

```
private synchronized void toogleStopped() { // guarded
    this.stop = !this.stop;

}

public synchronized boolean isStopped() { // guarded
   return this.stop;
}
```

**Events**

If some other object needs to react to changes in lights (react to "light has changed" event), use Observer design pattern as @TejasArjun suggested.

**Why `volatile` doesn't help**

`volatile` makes Java avoid assuming variable is not changed "from outside". So if a thread sets its value (or read it before), a second read will use (probably) a cached value (already saved in a CPU register or something). volatile makes Java always read the value from memory.

Said that, the lost update problem remains even with `volatile` keyword. One thread can 1) read 2) write. Another thread can do the same. And they can do it in this order:

Thread 1 reads false
Thread 2 reads false
Thread 1 sets true (assuming it read false)
Thread 2 sets true (assuming it read false)

And that's not nice :)

So you must tell Java to make read&write atomically. That's why we can use `synchronized` keyword to make sure a thread does the whole sync'ed block at once, not interlaced with another thread.

Comment: Also, If you need to do read/update atomically like helios pointed out, another option is going with [AtomicBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html). If only `TraffigLight` sets stop values on itself you don't need either.

Answer (score 0):

Put another way, Does this mean that cars need to listen to traffic light changes?. Observer design pattern may also help here.